# Avoiding overfitting with KDD CUP 1998 (python)

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am playing around with the KDD CUP 1998 data set and I have a couple questions I'm hoping some people can help me answer. For those of you who are not familiar with this data set, it is basically a list of people and whether they donated or not to a charity (including the amounts they donated).

Problem 1:
Dataset has around 95,000 records, however only 5% of them belong to class 1 (donated), rest are class 2. How do I deal with this when it comes to training to avoid overfitting?

Problem 2:
I want to approach this problem in 2 ways. Firstly, determine who will donate and who won't (maybe I'll use logistic regression and random forest classifiers?) and then I would like to determine how much a person will donate.. Any ideas on what possible methods I could try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20948/best-way-to-handle-unbalanced-multiclass-dataset-with-svm
Any modern ML lib will have weighting for class/sample [(sklearn for example)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html), thus you can penalize error on less frequent classes more than on frequent. Or you can resample data so that it becomes more balanced (duplicate objects from less frequent class several times in set, or delete objects of more frequent class).

2) Just try different classifiers like SVM, RF, AdaBoost on decision trees, and pick one that gives best results on test set.